# Посмотреть код новичка , дасть совет как улучшить код

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

```
/*
Создайте вектор , хранящий десят строковых значений "zero","one", ..,"nine".
Введите их в программу , преобразающую цифру в соответствующуу строковое представление.
Например при воде цифры 7 на экран должно выйте seven, усли набрать seven то на экран 
должно выйти 7 и т д.*/

void initilalize_numbert()
{
    numbers.push_back("zero");
    numbers.push_back("one");
    numbers.push_back("two");
    numbers.push_back("three");
    numbers.push_back("four");
    numbers.push_back("five");
    numbers.push_back("six");
    numbers.push_back("seven");
    numbers.push_back("eigth");
    numbers.push_back("nune");
    numbers.push_back("ten");
}

int get_numbers()
{

    const int not_a_symbol = numbers.size();

    // констатна размера вектора равна 11 элемента.

    int val = not_a_symbol; // присвоить значение константы переменной val.

    if (cin >> val) return val;

    cin.clear(); // очистка входного потока.
    /*
    строки if (cin >> val) return val; cin.clear(); означают , что если мы введём число
    больше чем константа not_a_symbol , а она равна 11 , т.к в нашем векторе 11 элементов
    то мы вернём число которое набрали даже если само число больше размера вектора.
    Это число успешно выведит поток cout и ввод продолжится далее.
    cin.clear() классная штука , очистит входной поток и продолжит работать корректно.
    */
    string s;
    cin >> s;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size();++i) /*перебераем элементы вектора*/
        if (numbers[i] == s) val = i; /*если строка равна элементам вектора пишем в val её индекс.*/
        return val;
}

string get_string()
{

    string s;

    int val;

    cin >> val;
    cin.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); ++i)
        if (i == val) s = numbers[i];
        return s;
}

int main()
try
{

    initilalize_numbert();
    /*наш вектор , где храним значения.*/

        while (true) 
        /*Бесконечный цикл true.*/
        {
            int val1 = get_numbers();
            /*Работаем с первой функцией.*/
            cout << val1 << '\n';

            string ss1 = get_string();
            /*Работаем со второй функцией.*/
            cout << ss1 << '\n';
        }
}
```

Если кто может посоветовать как улучшить код , откликнитесь)

Смысл в том что мне не нравится, что на входе main() приходится работать с двумя входными потоками , хотелось бы через один поток делать обе функции.

Comment: @MAX По условию задания вектор обязателен , если можно его выполнить по другому я с радостью приму любой опыт. Спасибо.

Comment: Больше не задавать вопросов в инфинитиве, так как это невежливо. Прочитать [требования к вопросам по инспекции кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info). Отредактировать вопрос, написать содержательный заголовок. =)

Comment: @Nick Volynkin Я извиняюсь за ошибки , этому есть оправдание , я учусь. Я уверен что в следующий раз я выполню все требования.

Comment: ничего страшного, надеюсь вы поняли, что это ирония )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализируйте вектор проще.
И нет никакой необходимости в двух входных потоках.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector <std::string> numbers = {"zero","one","two","three","four",
    "five","six","seven","eigth","nine","ten"};

    while (true) 
    {
        std::string val;
        std::cin >> val;
        if(val.size()<3)
        {
            try
            {
                int index = std::stoi(val);
                if(index<11) std::cout << numbers[index] << std::endl;
                else std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            }
            catch(...)
            {
                std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            for( i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++ )
            {
                if( numbers[i] == val )
                {
                    std::cout << i << std::endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i>10)std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cin.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Рецензия на рецензию - у вас int вместо size_t и велосипед вместо find.

Comment: Так не вопрос, а где Ваш "велосипед"? Человек просит улучшить код... Я его со своей точки зрения улучшил. А теперь, получается, Ваш ход. Вперед. Нет предела совершенству!

Comment: @Max ZS Мне не понятно , что делает условие `if(val.size()<3)` есть мысль что это кол-во значений на вход)

Comment: @its_space, Это введено конкретно для данного примера. Оно "определяет" введено ли число (которое в данном случае может состоять не более чем из двух символов [0-10]) или введено слово (любое из слов в данном случае состоит более чем из двух символов). Если это число, то производим конвертацию из строки непосредственно в число std::stoi и сопутствующий ему try-catch, хотя как вариант можно было использовать и старую добрую atoi).